# Syncing Heroku repo with GitHub

Tags: git, heroku

I had a `Git` repository with remotes added for `GitHub` and `Heroku`. I added several commits and pushed the commits to Heroku, leaving what was pushed to GitHub a few commits behind.

My computer was stolen, so I have lost my original code base.

I was able to clone the repository from Heroku, but of course GitHub is no longer in sync (because of the commits I added to Heroku).

What do I need to do to sync this repository with GitHub so it has the commits that were only added to Heroku, and be able to push to GitHub with proper commit history?

Comment: Not exactly sure how heroku works, but if it's a normal Git repository, just execute `git pull git://some.heroku.com/path/to/repo.git` from your repository. If that doesn't work, can you at least `scp` it down and create patches based on the commits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there was no commit specific to GitHub, all you need to do is:

- clone your Heroku repo
- add a remote url to your GitHub repo
- push to GitHub

That should be enough for GitHub to get the same commits as the ones in Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

This answer helped me resolve the issue other way around. I pushed the updates to GtiHub and needed to update heroku with latest changes. So here is what I did:

1. Clone the github repo

   - git clone git@github.com:user/app.git
2. Add remote url to heroku

   - cd app
   - git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:app.git
3. Push to heroku

   - git push heroku